# Java Swing using Socket for enterprise application

Tags: java, mysql, swing, sockets

After several months of searching & reading, now i need your help, taking in consideration the following:
- My Application Developed using Java Swing.
- MySQL has been used as database.
- JDBC has been used to make the communication between the application & database.
- The application will run on network environment with multiple client will connect to database.
- The application use Financial transactions, Posting, Billing ... etc.

** now i want to develop a server side that will work as middle-ware, this server side will do the following:
- Connecting to the database to retrieve data as client request.
- Business logic will be on the server side.
- Client will not know about the database.
- Queries Syntax will be on the server side.
- The Client will View,Save,Edit, Cancel ... etc, sending these actions to the server side & server will response.

--- I have read about JFC, J2EE, EJB ... etc, but i don't want to run my application from browser, it will be kept as desktop application only due to the complexity of the application.

--- So i will do it using Sockets.
Any ideas, or tutorials that i can follow?

Comment: See this example  maybe help http://srikanthtechnologies.com/articles/j2ee/ejb3fromswing.html

Comment: That really good, but can you give me a recommendation about the technology i'm working with? Many friends advising me to leave Swing & Desktop applications and focusing on web applications J2EE, but many times i feel those frameworks & tools not giving the developer the full control over the code. i like to control each peace of my code, so if there is a very good advice from you, i will appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a web-based approach to writing the back-end (e.g. a web service, either SOAP or Rest), and then communicating between the swing app and the back-end app via HTTP / HTTPS.

This is how mobile apps are typically written, and your swing desktop app is no different from a mobile app in this respect.

As far as frameworks for the back end, both Spring MVC and Grails make this pretty easy. Do yourself a huge favor and stay away from EJB unless you really need.it and understand why.

Answer (score 0):

When you have 1-2 hours left, it might be worth to look at the [Scout framework](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout).

Scout seems to be a pretty good fit to your application context. Scout applications consist of a Scout server that handles access to web services (currently including support for JAX-WS) and database access over JDBC. The Scout client communicates via HTTP(S) with the Scout server and is available in the form of desktop clients (either supporting Swing or SWT) and as web application (currently based on Eclipse RAP). The web client also supports different renderings to optimize the application to desktop browser or mobile devices with touch support.